# Handlebars Dynamic Partial Failover

Tags: handlebars.js

Is there a way to have partial failover when using dynamic partials?

[Handlebars partials documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html)
Shows dynamic partials, and only shows failover with hardcoded partial names.

Comment: I think the only way that you could do it would be by creating your own helper.

Comment: Relates to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824896/handlebars-failover-content-with-lookup-helper

Answer (score 0):

There is a github issue being tracked for this here - https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1371#issuecomment-361727713 - and link above includes a "hack" to achieve what you are wanting:

```
{{#>( lookup . 'intendedTemplate' )}}
  No template matched for "{{intendedTemplate}}"
{{/undefined}}
```

That is, you close your dynamic partial block with `{{/undefined}}`.