# Handlebars Failover Content With Lookup Helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am looking to render a handlebars partial via the Lookup helper. This isn't a problem, I can do that with this code:

```
{{> (lookup . 'type') }}
```

However, if the variable `type` doesn't render a value that is in my partials directory, then a 500 error throws. Handlebars supports this with failover content. Such as:

```
{{#> myPartial }}
  Failover content
{{/myPartial}}
```

My question is, can I combine the lookup with the failover?

I was hoping to do something like:

```
{{#> (lookup . 'type') }}
Failover content
{{/(lookup . 'type')}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you @76484 but I think I found what I was looking for:

`{{#> (lookup . 'type') }}<!-- Return Nothing if Undefined -->{{/undefined}}`

This avoids the need for a helper, and does exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I am unable to find any documentation on `{{/undefined}}`. Can you tell us where you found this?

Comment: Woah, just tested this and it _does_ indeed work! Also [@76484](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3397771/76484), to your question: this “feature” is entirely undocumented. However there is a useful discussion about a [normalized implementation in the HBS repo's issues](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1371)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to combine the [dynamic lookup helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) with the [partial block](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html#partial-block). However, I think we can come up with a custom helper that will do the job for us.

All that our helper needs to do is to take a partial name and try to find a partial by that name in the `Handlbars.partials` map. If it finds a partial, it will return the result of calling that partial template with the current data context. Otherwise, our helper will return the template within its block (the failover content).

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('partialResolver', function (partialName, options) {
    var partial = Handlebars.partials[partialName];

    if (partial && !Handlebars.Utils.isFunction(partial)) {
        Handlebars.partials[partialName] = partial = Handlebars.compile(partial);
    }

    return (partial ? partial : options.fn)(this);
});
```

Note: The condition in the middle is required because partials can be registered either as strings (which get compiled on demand) or as pre-compiled templates. If the partial is a *string*, we compile it and assign it to `Handlebars.partials[partialName]`.

I have created an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/pwq48afk/) for reference.